# How can I have charts that separate 2 criteria from select countries from my data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame containing movie information. I am trying to plot a horizontal stacked bar chart from 5 select countries counting the number of movies and TV Shows that are produced.

I have managed to plot a combined chart, but can't seem to separate it

```
q2h = netflix_df.loc[netflix_df['country'].isin(['United States','Japan','India','United Kingdom','South Korea'])]['type'].isin(['Movie', 'TV Show']).value_counts()
```

result of the variable:

```
Movie      3274
TV Show    1379
Name: type, dtype: int64
```

```
q2h.plot(kind = 'barh', y = [netflix_df.loc[netflix_df['country'].isin(['United States','Japan','India','United Kingdom','South Korea'])]], stacked = True)
```

[image: chart]